# Missing commands or icons on different Stack Exchange sites

Tags: bug, editor

I was trying to post some questions in the Finance Stack Exchange and it was missing some icons to edit the question, like bold, italics, etc. I thought it was normal, but I when I tried to post a question on Super User, the mentioned problem is still showing and even here in Meta. I have attached a screenshot from Super User. Can anyone help me solve this problem?

[image: screen shot of editor with missing buttons]

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: Any errors in your browser's dev tools/console? Sounds like some javascript is either being blocked entirely or at least erroring out during editor initialization.

Comment: firefox. The icons are showing in stack overflow, but not in other communities

Comment: Firefox ESR, by any chance?

Comment: @eLg what version of Firefox, exactly? If ESR then it's a very buggy browser, if you can change it then do it.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog Firefox Quantum 58.0.1. I do not have ESR

Comment: No repro on Windows 7 Home Premium 64 bit, Firefox 58.0.1

Comment: I have windows8